# How to read the origin date of file that was moved. It is different to the creation date or modification date

Tags: python, timestamp

When I move a file, the creation time will be changed, but not the displayed time in Explorer. 
(I am using Microsoft Windows 10 Home)

How do I get this origin creation time that was not modified? `os.path.getctime()` doesn´t work.

[image: printscreen of explorer]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJUE6.png)

Comment: try os.path.getmtime()

Comment: I think it is the date contained in the file itself, in EXIF tag.

Comment: Could you translate the screenshot? BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: os.path.getmtime() doesn´t work ad well. Sorry about the German pic. I now added a screenshot with English

Comment: Sorry the English printscreen doesn´t appear. The header of the file explorer is translated in English: Name, Date, Date Created, Date modified.